# How to retrieve file history from git repository using c#?

Tags: c#, .net, git

is there a way how to retrieve file history from git repository using c#? Some framework would be nice.

By file history I mean just names and change dates.

Comment: What do you mean by 'file history'? Just names and change dates or the whole file contents?

Comment: What do you mean with *history*: the list of commits where the file changed, an array of the "content" of the file through time, the `diff`-lists?

Comment: thanks Ash, but this look like GitHub API. I'm looking for git.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is [libgit2sharp](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp).

This very good library is, for example, used by Microsoft for visual studio support of git.

Feel free to look at the [wiki](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki) to get good examples...